# How to combine pdf documents

Tags: pdf

How do I combine 5 pdf documents I created in Word and put in one pdf file? I have tried several things, none of which work.

Answer (score 1):

I found that with pdf’s similarly created in Word I can open one pdf in Preview and simply « drag and drop » a second pdf (using its icon directly from its folder or desktop) into the pdf already open then save. This works well with the thumbnail view or « page sorter » visible on the left hand side of preview...

This also has the advantage of not needing a third party download as Preview is natively supplied so if you are in a controlled environment (Work or Uni) and are not allowed to install other software...

Answer (score 0):

Download the free app **[PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org)**. This stands for PDF split and merge. This app was written specifically to merge or split PDF files.